# How can I create and read compressed files and what compression should I use for python?

Tags: python, compression, pygame

I have a game I am writing in pygame and have map files. These are automatically generated by my game and I would like to compress/ decompress them before reading and writing to them so that my game goes quicker. The files are about 3 KB so they aren't that big. Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the how:  http://docs.python.org/library/archiving.html

For the which, that depends.  In fact, I'm not even sure that compression will help you out here.  But consider that gzip or bz2 might be a good choice if you want to compress individual files.  However, if you want to compress/decompress all of your map files together, then you'll want to consider a format that supports that, such as zipfile.

Comment: @user982270 - Please refer to the individual pages within the link.  Specifically, look under "Examples of usage".

Comment: @ziesemer: bz2 is similar to gzip in that it only compresses a single bytestream (file). zip supports more than one file. For multiple files with gzip or bz2, one usually first tars the files, then compresses.

Comment: @user982270: Python includes (follow ziesemer's link) a gzip module, and gzip.GZipFile is the *same API* as opening a file. It is braindead simple to use.